# Efficient diagonalization for block tridiagonal / banded sparse matrices?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix

Is there an efficient way to diagonalize a block tridiagonal NxN matrix? The matrix is made up of blocks of size 2K with N = 2 * K * K.

I need an algorithm that scales way better than the standard O(N^3) scaling, since I am usually interested in N ca. 20.000 and K ca.  100 and need to diagonalize a lot of them. I need both the eigenvalues AND the eigenvectors, if possible to full precision.

Further information, if useful: The matrix I am considering is hermitian, the off-diagonal matrices are just the unit matrix and the matrices on the main diagonal are pentagonal. I implemented the exact form of my matrix in this minimal reproducable example (python):

```
import scipy.linalg as linalg
import numpy as np

#N is usually in this form and I want to be able to have a code that is still fast, if  I set K to a 50 or 100
K = 5
N = 2* K**2

#Creating Matrix in my form...

N_band_max = 2*K

#setting bands...
Main = np.random.random(N)
Diag1 = np.random.random(N-1) + 1j*np.random.random(N-1)
Diag2 = np.ones(N-2)
Diag3 = np.ones(N-N_band_max) 

#This is for the block tridiagonal structure

for i in range(len(Diag2)):
    if(i%N_band_max == N_band_max-2 or i%N_band_max == N_band_max-1):
        Diag2[i] = 0.
        
for i in range(len(Diag1)):
    if(i%2 == 1 ):
        Diag1[i] = 0.


H = np.diag(Main) + np.diag(Diag1,1) + np.diag(Diag1.conjugate(),-1) + np.diag(Diag2,2) + np.diag(Diag2.conjugate(),-2) + np.diag(Diag3,N_band_max) + np.diag(Diag3.conjugate(),-N_band_max)

#Up to here, I just created a matrix in the desired form, for reproducibility.
#This is the part I want to be FASTER. Basically, if you find any function
#that produces the same output for the constructed matrix in less time for big K, the question is solved.
EigVals,EigVecs = linalg.eigh(H)
```

(The same question from a mathematical standpoint and with a nice latex format is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427654/diagonalizing-a-block-tridiagonal-matrix)

Comment: The implementations here may be of relevance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately I am interested in ALL eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix, not only in some of them. Typically Lanczos algorithm is only more efficient when one is interested in the lowest few eigenvalues and -vectors

Comment: Unless you are prepared to write code with `numba` or `cython`, you won't get anything more efficient than one of the `scipy.linalg` options.  Those use well written compiled libraries.